# Ubuntu 16.04.1 - No splash screen on boot - Intel Graphics

Tags: boot, intel-graphics

I want to start by saying I am a complete noob when it comes to anything Linux. If I need to edit a file or inputting commands (where?) I might need explaining on how to go about editing it.

I'm not getting a splash screen when I boot. It's not really a huge deal just one of those mildly annoying kinds of things lol.

Here is what my boot sequence is like:
[image]

I should note that I do get a very brief splash screen when shutting down.

It starts with the blank purple screen for several seconds, flashes that line of text at the top after, then goes to black screen for several more seconds and then I'm at desktop.

My computer specs are as follows (Dell Studio 1555):

- Intel Core 2 Duo T6500 / 2.1 GHz
- 4GB DDR 2
- Intel GMA 4500MHD (Graphics)

I've searched online and seen others with a similar issue, but a lot of the people seem to be having issue after installing propriety drivers. But my splash screen as never worked.

I've tried installing [this](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2) and the issue persists.

I'd appreciate any help you could provide on this issue.

edit: Output from `cat /proc/cmdline`

`BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic root=UUID=ead2a23a-f1fe-4adb-908e-18fbdb7602b8 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What's the output to `cat /proc/cmdline`?  Please [edit] your question,add the info, and then leave a comment @fabby

Comment: For what it's worth, the same thing happens on my secondary computer with an AMD Athlon B28 and the integrated AMD graphics...

Comment: Plymouth needs special setup for AMD and Nvidia but I haven't played with that yet.

Comment: @Fabby Hello. Could you explain to me how I would go about finding out what the output to cat/proc/cmdline is? Edit: I'm sorry for the late response, I've been busy past couple days.

Comment: @Fabby I have updated the post to include output from `cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: Mmh, that looks good: `splash` should show the slash screen,,,  Sorry, no more bright ideas except turning it off?